# Focus on list item child views

Tags: android, focus, listitem

Is it possible for child views of a list item to receive focus? I have a custom list
view. Each row has a linear layout with two views, a button and a textview. I want to 
get the click event on the button and also have the background change color with focus.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that was hard to read. You should edit the question and try to explain yourself better.

To enable a click listener on those buttons you must add the listener inside the getView() method of the adapter. If you are using the View Holder Pattern

```
holder.button.setOnClickListener(...)
```

and then access the parent or whatever to change the background.

If you don't know what I'm talking about with that holder thing, watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA), it's at the beginning.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

From what I could decipher from your question [this](http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/125/) might be what you need.

Don't quote your own sentences. Also reading what you have typed, before clicking Post would save a lot of effort spent in understanding the question.